# Android detect Done key press for OnScreen Keyboard

Tags: android

Is it possible to detect when the <kbd>Done</kbd> key of onScreen keyboard was pressed ?

Answer (score 295, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            // do your stuff here
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Note that you will have to import the following libraries:

```
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

Comment: Thank you, you gave me a great starting point. Just I needed to use `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH` for the lens search-button instead.

Comment: Hi, Is this possible with ButterKnife?@mikeyaworski@SzabolcsBerecz

Comment: @MaulikDodia You can use butterknife's @OnEditorAction()

Comment: Remember to add `android:imeOptions:actionDone` to make this work in your XML layout if using a `TextInputEditText`

Answer (score 3):

> An Editor Info is most useful class when you have to deal with any
>   type of user input in your Android application. For e.g. in
>   login/registration/search operations we can use it for more accurate
>   keyboard input. An editor info class describes several attributes for
>   text editing object that an input method will be directly
>   communicating with edit text contents.

You can try with **[IME_ACTION_DONE](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html#IME_ACTION_DONE)** .

This action performs a <kbd>Done</kbd> operation for nothing to input and the **`IME`** will be closed.

Using **[setOnEditorActionListener](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setOnEditorActionListener(android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener))**

```java
EditTextObj.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        boolean handled = false;
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            /* Write your logic here that will be executed when user taps next button */
            handled = true;
        }
        return handled;
    }
});
```

Comment: How to handle the same problem with custom keyboard ?

Answer (score 1):

Using Butterknife you can do this

```
@OnEditorAction(R.id.signInPasswordText)
boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event){
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
        /* Write your logic here that will be executed when user taps next button */
    }
    return false;
}
```