# Android: Detect when "Done" key is pressed on softkey

Tags: android, onclick, android-softkeyboard, detect, onclicklistener

I want to detect when the soft key "done" is pressed so that when it is, it a toast message appears. I saw this post about the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077425/android-detect-done-key-press-for-onscreen-keyboard) however, I am confused about how exactly to implement the solution.

The solution provided is:

```
 editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

 editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
     @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            // toast message
        }
        return false;
    }
 });
```

my question is this:

1. is editText suppose to be defined under the onCreate method?
2. is the entire code suppose to be under the onCreate method?

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes. Unless you only want to activate the `EditText` under certain conditions then you can put it where the `EditText`comes into play if you'd like (like on click event, in a runnable or after a web call) it comes down to preference.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your `EditText` where ever you like. I tend to split everything up into smaller methods,because I think it makes code easier to change, but it is a very common practice to put almost everything in the `onCreate` method, because it makes code easier to follow when you are not jumping back and forth between different methods.

Answer (score 0):

`editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);`

THIS MUST BE CALLED AFTER `setContentView`

Set in your layout on that edit text ImeOption 
otherwise you never catch that DONE action.

```
public ... extends Activity
{

public void onCreate(Bundle ...)
{
super...
setContentVIew...


editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

 editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
     @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            // toast message
        }
        return false;
    }
 });

}
}
```

---

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
             >
```

Answer (score 0):

**import :**

```
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
```

try with the following code when on key of perticular edit text.

**Code :**

```
ed.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

@Override

public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stubi

            Log.d("View", "conLL.getWidth() "+conLL.getWidth());

            if (event.getKeyCode()==66 && enteredNumber>0) {

            Log.d("View", "------------------------ ");

             } 
            return false;
        }
});
```