# Catch "DONE" key press from soft keyboard

Tags: java, android

I'm looking for code that can catch key press of "DONE" button from soft keyboard. When done button is pressed, I need to change button state to enabled and user then can move on to the next activity.

I found this piece of code, here on stackoverflow, but I can't implement it without errors. Can you help me please?

```
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
       if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
           // do your stuff here
       }
       return false;
}
});
```

Here is entire .java file

```
package com.example.start201;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FirstActivity extends Activity {

   private EditText editText;

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.layout_firstactivity);

       editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

       editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
               if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                   // do your stuff here
               }
               return false;
           }
       });

}


}
```

Comment: What errors do you have?

Comment: Do you think that the errors are just random and useless?  Why not tell us what errors you get?

Comment: I get these errors: Multiple markers at this line
 - The method setOnEditorActionListener(TextView.OnEditorActionListener) in the type TextView is not applicable 
  for the arguments (new OnEditorActionListener(){})
 - OnEditorActionListener cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Did you import `OnEditorActionListener`? Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004344/android-edittext-imeoptions-done-track-finish-typing and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077425/android-detect-done-key-press-for-onscreen-keyboard

Comment: define "errors". fix your imports.

Comment: Thanks for the clues guys. Now I get it and it's working fine. Next time I'll define my questions more precisely.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got it sorted, this code runs smoothly and it recognizes key press of DONE button from soft keyboard.

Layout file:

```
   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="NEXT"
    android:textSize="10sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

.java file:

```
package com.example.drywallcalculator102v;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener;

public class FirstActivity extends Activity {

   private EditText editText;
   private Button btnNext;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.layout_firstactivity);

       btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
       btnNext.setEnabled(false);

       editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

       editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

           @Override
           public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                   // do your stuff here
                   btnNext.setEnabled(true);
               }
               return false;
           }
       });

   }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

try adding this import:

```
import android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener;
```