# Intercept D-Pad presses in EditText on Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to listen for arrow key (dpad) presses in an `EditText`, on a softkey keyboard.  I've tried multiple approaches, but nothing has triggered the key event to be sent to any listener or overridden method when the arrow keys are pressed.  The backspace key works, but many other keys do not, including the ones I want.

What I have tried so far:

- `editText.setOnKeyListener`
- `editText.setKeyListener`
- `new editText() {
    @Override
    onKeyDown()
  }`

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution answering another SO question, though it may be kludgy, it will work.  THeir solution is to handle lost focus of EditView.

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627137/how-can-i-know-when-a-edittext-lost-focus)

Comment: The problem is that focus is never lost when pressing the D-Pad.  There are no other controls for focus to move to.  Unless you are suggesting I make some invisible controls... but that's definitely more kludgy than I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shot in the dark, maybe [KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT) or one of the other constants in the KeyEvent class? You could try checking for each arrow event in an `OnEditorActionListener`, like in this other SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5077543/475217

Comment: The constants are what I'm checking for. And the action listener isn't being called either, unfortunately (which I am already using for listening to the enter key).