# EditText is cleared after pressing done & is acting weird

Tags: android, android-edittext

Attached to my `EditText` is a `new` `TextView.OnEditorActionListener()`

```
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {

 if(i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){

  dataSnapshot.child("add").child(child.getKey()).child("comment").getRef().setValue(String.valueOf(serviceComment.getText()));
  return true;

 }else{

  return false;

 }

}
```

After execution, the text inside my `EditText` is cleared when I want it to persist.

Additionally, after it is cleared, and I type in the same exact thing, the code doesn't execute and the keyboard doesn't disappear until I type in something different from what I previously typed.

My ultimate goal is to have the text within my `EditText` to persist after clicking done and hiding the keyboard.

Here is the XML for my `EditText`

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtComment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorSecondary"
        android:hint="Enter a comment"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:maxLength="200"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Comment: Have u tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/5077543/7666442 because its working fine for me

Comment: Yes, my code is identical to that one. I'm not sure what you mean. onEditorAction() is called automatically on a keyboard event. I have my code posted at the top

Comment: Test case remove `return true;` from `if(i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){}`

Comment: doesn't work. text is still cleared after clicking "done"

Comment: debug and watch serviceComment.getText()

Comment: Did you check if there is other listener set to your `txtComment` edittext? Like `TextWatchers` or something.

Comment: @Teptis The listener is applied right after declaring the edittext. that's the only code applied to the edittext

Answer (score 0):

To hide the keyboard you have to perform this inside the listener callback:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Please try it.

Also, the Edit Text clear issue might be due to the line:
dataSnapshot.child("add").child(child.getKey()).child("comment").getRef().setValue(String.valueOf(serviceComment.getText()));

This line might be causing UI Hang and can be the reason.

Try calling that operation in another thread.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my problems is that my EditText is being cleared after hitting the "done" button on the keyboard

Comment: I have a doubt: The EditText code you've shared is having width 0dp but there is no weight mentioned. How it could be? just curious

Comment: 0dp when attached to a constraint layout matches constraint

Comment: Could you try once by commenting the dataSnapshot.child("add").child(c....... line?

Comment: After commenting that line out, the text stays, but my code wont get executed. Hmm. why would it clear the text after executing that code?

Comment: Ah Yes! I think that's a db operation and since we don't know whats the logic you are doing, I can't say a solution. Could you check the logcat, may be its doing too much work and UI is hanged.

Comment: I believe you're right. I don't see why it would clear my text or appear to clear it. Perhaps it just appears to clear it. I'll try writing a function for the database and call it from the onEditorAction and see if that works.

Comment: Try calling that operation in separate thread using a Handler or something, which will definitely solve the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179953/discussion-between-harish-jose-and-garren-fitzenreiter).

Comment: Still not a solution. Anytime the db code is called, it clears out the edittext